# Incorrect Comparisons And Swaps Counter Output for Quicksort Function

Tags: c++

Im currently trying to implement a c++ program which compares the  number of swaps and comparisons in a variety of different sorting methods. The program appears to be working perfectly for all sorting methods (selection sort, insertion sort) except quicksort which only outputs a comparison and swap count of 0 no matter the data size or order of the list. Ive included the full program below. The quicksort function is definitely working its only the counting element which isn't which is strange since it uses external compare and swap functions which are meant to increment the appropriate counter each time they are called. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;
unsigned long long comparisons = 0;
unsigned long long swaps = 0;

bool comp_less(int a, int b){
    ++comparisons;

    if ( comparisons == std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() )
    {
        std::cout << "Number of comparisons reached max value. Resetting it 0.\n";
        swaps = 0;
    }

    return a < b;
}

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    ++swaps;

    if ( swaps == std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() )
    {
        std::cout << "Number of swaps reached max value. Resetting it 0.\n";
        swaps = 0;
    }

    int t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

void selectionSort(int *first, int *last)
{

    for(int *i = first; i < (last - 1); ++i){
        int *min = i;
        for(int *j = i + 1; j < last; ++j){
            if(comp_less(*j, *min)){
                min = j;
            }
        }
        swap(*i, *min);
    }

}


void insertionSort(int* first, int* last)
{
    for (int *i = first + 1; i < last; ++i)
    {
        int temp = *i;
        int *j;
        for (j = i; j > first && comp_less(temp, *(j - 1)); --j)
        {
            swap(*j, *(j - 1));
        }
        *j = temp;
    }
}
int *partition(int *first, int *last)
{

    int *pivot = last - 1;
    int *i = first;
    int *j = last - 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        while (comp_less(*i, *pivot) && i < last)
        {
            ++i;
        }
        while (*j >= *pivot && j > first)
        {
            --j;
        }
        if (i >= j)
            break;

        swap(*i, *j);
    }
    swap(*(last - 1), *i);
    return i;
}

void quickSort(int* first, int* last) {
    {
        if ((first - last) <= 1)
            return;
        int *pivot = partition(first, last);

        quickSort(first, pivot);
        quickSort(pivot + 1, last);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string algorithm = "selection";
    string dataset = "random";

    for (int c; (c = getopt(argc, argv, "ravqsin")) != -1;) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'r':
                dataset = "random";
                break;
            case 'a':
                dataset = "sorted";
                break;
            case 'v':
                dataset = "reverse";
                break;
            case 'q':
                algorithm = "quicksort";
                break;
            case 's':
                algorithm = "selection";
                break;
            case 'i':
                algorithm = "insertion";
                break;
            case 'n':
                algorithm = "none";
                break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    const int size = argc > 0 ? atoi(argv[0]) : 10000;
    int* data = new int[size];

    if (dataset == "sorted") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = i;
        }
    }
    else if (dataset == "reverse") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = size - i - 1;
        }
    }
    else if (dataset == "random") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = rand() % size;
        }
    }

    if (algorithm == "quicksort") {
        quickSort(data, data + size);
    }
    else if (algorithm == "selection") {
        selectionSort(data, data + size);
    }
    else if (algorithm == "insertion") {
        insertionSort(data, data + size);
    }
    else if (algorithm=="none"){
        cout<< "Oops!" <<'\n';
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "OK" << '\n';
    cout << "Algorithm:   " << algorithm << '\n';
    cout << "Data set:    " << dataset << '\n';
    cout << "Size:        " << size << '\n';
    cout << "Swaps:       " << swaps << '\n';
    cout << "Comparisons: " << comparisons << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this: `using namespace std;`. If some header that you include additionally includes the header where `std::swap` is defined, you can get into troubles. Anyway, +1 for reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `quickSort` function, change

```
if ((first - last) <= 1)
```

to

```
if ((last - first) <= 1)
```

Comment: thank you so much, ive been racking my brains for hours trying to figure this out. If you have the time would you be able to explain to me the logic to why this was stopping my counters?

Comment: `data - (data + size)` is always `<= 1` ... is the reason...

Comment: It wasn't stopping the counters. It simply didn't sort anything, since the very first call of `quickSort` immediately returned. You could always check this out by debugging, or putting some debugging messages/asserts into your functions. You could also check whether is the array sorted at the end.

Comment: @DanielLangr that makes perfect sense, ill make sure to next time, appreciate your time

Comment: @DanielLangr running the test on the reverse and ordered list in debug mode i start getting a segmentation fault when i start testing lists above size 50 000, however when randomly sorted i don't, any idea why this may be happening

Comment: @NicholasFischer Quicksort has the _average_ complexity _O(n log(n))_, but the _worst-case_ complexity _O(n^2)_. In the latter case, the recursion is very deep, basicaly the number of recursive calls is _O(n)_, which may cause stack overflow. There are techniques how to avoid this, such as _tail-call-elimination_, and, mainly, better pivot selection (_median-of-three_, _median-of-nine_, randomized selection, etc.). You can always study proved implementations such as those from C++ standard libraries. Note that they are much more complex than your "classroom" version.

Comment: Ordered and/or reverse-ordered data are typical for quicksort worst-cases. Ideally, one would randomly permute data before running quicksort, but we usually don't do this in practice because it is slow. That may explain why you observe such behavior for your input data sets (ordered vs random).

Comment: @DanielLangr is there any method to extend the container size i am working with to account for this without changing the quicksort method itself, i recognise these are the worst-case scenarios and after this i'll be implementing several of the methods you mentioned to improve the performance however i'll be unable to compare the swaps and comparisons between the old and improved versions since the old stackoverflows.

Comment: @NicholasFischer The only option I see, without changing the algorithm itself, is to randomly shuffle the data. But this basically create random case.